# Display Suite layouts not working for field collections Edit\Add forms

Tags: entities, display-suite

Even though I have the Display Suite Forms module enabled and applied a layout to this specific field collection, it does nothing for the edit/add forms. If I apply a layout using manage display it works when viewing the appropiate view mode (for example the full view mode).

Does anybody have any idea or hints where I could start looking?

Comment: I've ran into the same issue today, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar problem with ds and heartbeat module. Maybe my solutions also works for this problem. Just enable the needed submodules in ds - that fixed the problem.